# Azure service bus trigger function: determine if current attempt is the last one

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

Before a service bus queue message is moved to a DLQ, I need to clean up some resources associated with the message. Obviously the message's `DeliveryCount` should be compared with the queue's `MaxDeliveryCount` to determine if this is the last attempt or not. How can I get the `MaxDeliveryCount` from within an Azure function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Service Bus admin client and get it through the MaxDeliveryCount property [Admin client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.queueproperties.maxdeliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_Administration_QueueProperties_MaxDeliveryCount)

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;
var adminclient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(yourconnectionstring);
QueueProperties runtime = await adminclient.GetQueueAsync(queuename);
Console.WriteLine("Max delivery count is" + runtime.MaxDeliveryCount);
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I find it a bit awkward that the `QueueProperties` is not referenced from a `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` property.